# how to display message after 5secs when data is not loaded?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am calling an api to fetch data from database. I want to display message when data is not loaded after 5 secs or internet is not connected. 
how can i add timer starts from calling an api and after 5secs display message when data is not loaded?

home.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
 this._myservice.myservice(this.taskdesc).subscribe(data => {
    this.displaydata = data;
    }); 
}
```

homeservice.ts

```
 myservice(taskdesc) {
    console.log(">>" + this.loggedinuser);
    let params = '&taskdesc=' + taskdesc;

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this._http.post(this._url + this.loggedinuser+this._urlend+this.loggedinuser, params, {headers: headers})
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());

  }
```

> Please advise.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.timeout(5000)` from Observable

```
return this.http.post()
.timeout(5000, new Error('Your Message'))
.map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

Comment: there is an error that timout is not a function.
my code::----
 var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this._http.post(this._url+this.loggedinuser+this._urlend+this.loggedinuser,params,{headers:headers})
      .timeout(5000,new Error('Something went wrong, Please try again later.')).map((response:Response) =>this.dataa=response.json());

Comment: Have you `import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';` ?

Comment: @KirandeepKaur, so what do you need ? it will return error after 5 secs , if you don't get data.

Comment: it is showing an error -->  Argument of type 'Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IScheduler'. Property 'now' is missing in type 'Error'.

Comment: @KirandeepKaur, That's another issue that might be coz of some other code in your porject , the question was how you can show message after some time. I think you should post  another question with detailed code and new issue.